# How to simplify an ocunit assertion that contains NSUInteger?

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

I have a passing test that works fine, but I'd like to know how I might simplify the assertion to be 1 line instead of 3 (how to cast these inline basically)

```
- (void)testResponseDataResetWhenResponseReceived
{
    self.sut.responseData = self.data;
    [self.sut connection:nil didReceiveResponse:nil];
    NSUInteger len = self.data.length; //this data type is NSData *
    NSUInteger expectedLen = 0;
    STAssertEquals(len, expectedLen, @"NSData was not reset");
}
```

**UPDATE**

I landed on this solution

```
STAssertEquals([self.data length], 0U, @"NSData was not reset");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using [OCHamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/TutorialObjectiveC)?

```
assertThatInt(self.data.length, equalToInt(0));
```

You could even write a custom matcher:

```
assertThat(self.data, is(reset()));
```